# Calling an async JS function within if condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to generate a unique token, so I have to check if the token value already exists in the MongoDB database. I am checking inside if condition if the token already exists. Though in development mode I have only a few tokens in the database, so the random value must be generating something different, but once in production, there will be many token.

My question is will the if condition wait for database to query and return output from `alreadyExists` function below? Or being async, it will move down and `generateToken()` again?

Here is the code,

```
//Function to check if string already exists
function alreadyExists(val) {
  doc.findOne({token: val}).exec(function(err, docObj){
    if(!docObj) return 0; //If token not found, send a false
    else if (err) return 1; //If error or token, send a false value
    else return 1; //If token found, send a true value
  });
}

//Function to generate a random token
function generateToken() {
  var t = Math.floor(((Math.random() * 9) + 1.111)*1000); //Generates number between 1000 and 9999
  if(!alreadyExists(t)) //Check if token not already exists
    return t; //Return the token
  generateToken(); //Call recursively again until unique token is generated
}
```

Also, is the code for random correct? I have to generate number actually in between 1111 and 9999 (excluding range end, though including is also fine)

Comment: Can you post your code where you will be calling these functions? Right now they are just defined, so neither will run. The answer will vary depending on the contexts of both of these functions

Comment: I am just calling the generate function. Like this, `var token = generateToken();`

Comment: I think your random generator will work as long as the `Math.random()` function returns a number less than `.9876666...`. That is, 98.7666% of the time. The way I would do it is:

1. Get the range difference (9999 - 1111 = 8888)
2. Create a random number between 0 and that difference (`Math.random() * 8888`)
3. Add that to the lower bound (`1111 + that`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look more into [Javascript Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) if you want to call an asynchronous function. Right now your function will already return undefined in an if statement, because it did not have time to execute, aka making your if statement always `if (!false)`, as undefined is falsy.
Wrap your other function in a promise and use `.then()` notation to catch the value.

```
function alreadyExists(val) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    doc.findOne({token: val}).exec(function(err, docObj){
      if(!docObj) resolve(0); //If token not found, resolve falsy value
      else if (err) reject(err) //If error reject
      else return resolve(1); //If token found, resolve truthy value
    });
  });
}

//Function to generate a random token
function generateToken() {
  var t = Math.floor(((Math.random() * 9) + 1.111)*1000); //Generates number between 1000 and 9999
  alreadyExists(t)
  .then((value) => {//.then() waits for promise to resolve
    if(!value){ //Check if token not already exists
      return t; //Return the token
    }else{
      generateToken(); //Call recursively again until unique token is generated
    }
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    console.log("Error:",err) //catch any thrown errors
  })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Promise`, and the new `await` / `async` functionality to block.

```
//Function to check if string already exists
async function alreadyExists(val) {
  return new Promise(function(reject, resolve){
      doc.findOne({token: val}).exec(function(err, docObj){
        if(!docObj) reject(0); //If token not found, send a false
        else if (err) reject(err); //If error or token, send a false value
        else resolve(1); //If token found, send a true value
      });
  })
}

//Function to generate a random token
function generateToken() {
  var t = Math.floor(((Math.random() * 9) + 1.111)*1000); //Generates number between 1000 and 9999
  if(! await alreadyExists(t)) //Check if token not already exists
    return t; //Return the token
  generateToken(); //Call recursively again until unique token is generated
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the if statement will not wait for the async function to complete. You're gonna have to pass a callback function into the alreadyExists function

```
function alreadyExists(val, callback) {
  doc.findOne({token: val}).exec(function(err, docObj){
    if(!docObj) callback(0); //If token not found, send a false
    else if(err) callback(1); //If error or token, send a false value
    else callback(1); //If error or token, send a false value
  });
}

//Function to generate a random token
function generateToken(callback) {
  var t = Math.floor(((Math.random() * 9) + 1.111)*1000); //Generates number between 1000 and 9999
  alreadyExists(t, (exists) => {
      if(!exists) callback(t); //Check if token not already exists
      else generateToken(callback); //Call recursively again until unique token is generated
  })
}
```

Alternatively, you can use promises.